# Can I email only Items within Custom List?

Tags: custom-list

In SharePoint 2013 I created a Custom List to communicate with my team. Can I email only the Items themselves (one at a time), or am I only able to email the entire Custom List with all the Items together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view using the filter by [ME]
2. Suscribe each member to this view

Comment: Not sure I understand.

Comment: I understood that you need that each team member receive alerts for your own items. Then I guess you have a column to assign to the person. Then you can create a view filtering by [ME]. If the person subscribes to that view only you receive their items by email.